# Issue with virtual hosts in Mac OSX Lion with MAMP

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, mamp

I'm having issues connecting my virtual hosts. Here's my code. Is there anything missing here?

**In httpd.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName site1.local
DocumentRoot "/Users/Dan/Dropbox/Websites/www/site1"
</VirtualHost>
```

**In /etc/hosts**

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       site1.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong here. I needed to change the default port on MAMP to 80.